# Rails 5.1 error retrieving user (as contact) from db when displaying p

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, centos7

I have set up a Rails 5/bootstrap theme which which is set to root 'creatives#index' in routes.rb, with Creatives theme ([Start Bootstrap.com](http://startbootstrap.com), using frontend-generators gem) and files in app/views/creatives folder as an index.html.erb rendering partials of all sections. All fine and I generated a contact model for new users to login/signup/send forms etc. This tested fine also (with db migrations) after I added password and email validation, all checked out fine.

However when I try to access the contacts show page (which is in app/views/contacts folder, next to creatives (to which the root is set) I get an error on displaying when navigating to :3000/contacts/1 which is the only contact added to the contacts db. The record is definitely there with id  = 1.

The error is below

```
Started GET "/contacts/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-09 23:37:02 +0100
Processing by ContactsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Contact Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Return value is: nil

So it returns a value of nil although there is only 1 row in db with the correct id. It seems to be taking the correct params from contacts_controller.rb which is below

def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    debugger
  end
  def new
  end

So I cant figure out whether its a routing problem (contacts is not linked to creatives ?) or there is a db error somewhere (its postgresql)

The routes.rb is below

Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :contacts
root 'creatives#index'
end
```

Tips welcome! Thanks

Comment: `@contact = Contact.find(params[:id])` should raise a `ActiveRecord::NotFoundError` is the record cannot be  found. Your routes are fine - and bootstrap is completely irrevant.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find

Comment: Also you mention an error - what error? Its not in your question.

Comment: Started GET "/contacts/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-09 23:37:02 +0100
Processing by ContactsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Contact Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Return value is: nil

Comment: The return value is nil but the record is definitely in the database ?

Comment: Can you verify that with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Started GET "/contacts/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-10 08:58:46 +0100
Processing by ContactsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Contact Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Return value is: nil

Comment: ContactsController.rb is below[1, 8] in /home/anton/workspace/railscreative/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb
   1: class ContactsController < ApplicationController
   2:  def show
   3:     @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
   4:     debugger
=> 5:   end
   6:   def new
   7:   end
   8:   end
(byebug)

Comment: I did create the model before I created the controller though if that makes any difference ?

Comment: routes file is now - Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'contacts/new'

resources :contacts
get  'contacts/show'
root 'creatives#index'
end

Comment: One more thing, the original contacts table had 4 entries and the one I'm using now was no 4, however I deleted the other 3 and reset the seq to 1 for the current entry, could this have something to do with the return value nil ? (postgresql)

Comment: Sorry it was an error in my show page, it returns id =1 fine. Thanks